# How to save One to Many relationqhip data at same time using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, laravel

I'm trying to store data into a database and I encountered a situation where I don't know is it feasible or not to do that.

so I have two following tables in the database

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('castings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_casting');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('cine');
            $table->string('date_naissance');
            $table->integer('lieu_naissance');
            $table->string('mineur');
            $table->integer('id_representant')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('id_representant')->references('id_representant')->on('representants');
        });
    }
```

And the table representants :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('representants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->increments('id_representant');
            $table->string('nom_prenom');
            $table->string('cine');
            $table->string('lien_casting');
            $table->integer('actif');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My Models :

```
class Casting  Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
extends     protected $fillable = ["id_casting",
        "nom", "prenom" , "cine" , "date_naissance","lieu_naissance" ,"mineur"
    ];


    public function representants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Representant');
}

}
```

And The Model Representant:

```
class Representant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = ["id_representant",
            "nom_prenom", "cine" , "lien_casting","actif"
    ];


    function castings() {

    return $this->hasMany('Casting');
}

}
```

And I have the following form :

```
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castingss"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />
                    <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" >
                         
                       </div> 
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="casting_name">Prénom</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" >
                     
                       </div>
                       </div>
                     <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cine" name="cine" placeholder="Cin">
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="casting_date_naissancee">Date de naissance</label>
                         <div class="input-group date">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_naissance" name="date_naissance">
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                            <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                        </span> 
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="casting_lieu_naissance">Lieu de naissance</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lieu_naissance" name="lien_naissance" placeholder="Lieu de naissance">
                       </div>
                     </div>  
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container" hidden>
                    <label for="guarantor">Nom et prénom du représentatnt légal </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_prenom" name="nom_prenom" placeholder="Représentant">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_identification_number-container" hidden>
                    <label for="guarantor_identification_number">CIN du représentatnt légal</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cine" name="cine" placeholder="CINE">
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_lien-container" hidden>
                    <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Lien</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lien_casting" name="lien_casting" placeholder="Lien">
                </div>      
                   
                
                    <div class="form-group" align="center">
                      <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                      <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" />
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-6">
                      <span id="form_result"></span>
                    </div>
                 </form>
```

I managed to insert the data into a single table, but I found the complexity at this level:

It is that at the time of the insertion in my form when I calculate the age from the date of birth and I find that the age is less than 18 years I must insert in the castings table the id of the representant and insert it in the table representans the information name of the representative, cine of the representative and the link, and all at the same time.

Is it possible to do that? if you have any idea that will help me I would be grateful.

**UPDATED**

I did the following code in my Controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)

{

      $representants = new Representant();
      $castings = new Casting();
  
      $date = $request['date_naissance']; // 24/8/1995
      $age = Carbon::now()->format('Y')- Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/YYYY', $date)->format('Y');

      if ($age < 18) {

             $representants->nom_prenom = $request['nom_prenom'];
             $representants->cine = $request['cine'];
             $representants->lien_casting = $request['lien_casting'];
          // assign your data to the models needed
             $representants->save();
             $castings->nom = $request['nom'];
             $castings->prenom = $request['prenom'];
             $castings->cine = $request['cine'];
             $castings->date_naissance = $request['date_naissance'];
             $castings->lieu_naissance = $request['lieu_naissance'];
           //  $representant->lien_casting = $request['lien_casting'];
             $castings->representant_id = $representants->representant_id;
             $castings->save();
  }else{
     
             $castings->nom = $request['nom'];
             $castings->prenom = $request['prenom'];
             $castings->cine = $request['cine'];
             $castings->date_naissance = $request['date_naissance'];
             $castings->lieu_naissance = $request['lieu_naissance'];

  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
{message: "Unexpected data found. ↵Data missing",…}
exception: "Carbon\\Exceptions\\InvalidFormatException"
file: "D:\\Projet_Cast_Infl\\vendor\\nesbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Traits\\Creator.php"
line: 643
message: "Unexpected data found.\r\nData missing"
trace: [{file: "D:\Projet_Cast_Infl\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php", line: 665,…},…]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can! :) But majority of what you want should be done in the controller.

**yourController.php** (the controller you're posting to)

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $representant = new Representant();
  $castings = new Casting();
  
  $date = $request['casting_date_naissance'] // 24/8/1995
  $age = Carbon::now()->format('Y') - Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y');

  if ($age < 18) {
  $representant->nom = $casting->nom = $request['casting_name'];
  // assign your data to the models needed

  $representant->save();
  $casting->representant_id = $representant->id;
  $casting->save()
  }
  
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur help , Please check mu Update

Comment: `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y')` Try to change your `d/m/Y` to how your date is inputed, the exception is saying there's a difference between input date and date format.